# How to convert List[Any] to List(Int,Int) in scala?

Tags: scala

I have `List[Any]` which has values

```
List((0,0), (1,1), (1,3), (2,2), (3,1))
```

I want to convert it into

```
List[(Int,Int)]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that the type of every member will be (Int, Int), then just use `asInstanceOf`:

```
val l:List[Any] = List((0,0), (1,1), (1,3), (2,2), (3,1))

l.map(_.asInstanceOf[(Int, Int)])
```

Comment: You can just cast the list, like Chris Martin says. You don't have to cast every tuple separately.

Answer (score 7):

You can use collect method, so that it will not fail in case  List contains not only tuples of Ints

```
val l: List[Any]  = List((0,0), (1,1), (1,3), (2,2), (3,1))
l.collect{ case (a: Int, b: Int) => (a,b)}
```

Comment: When I use this code for converting double then it converts into Path2D.Double. what is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 6):

You can just cast it using `asInstanceOf`.

```
scala> val a: List[Any] = List((0,0), (1,1), (1,3), (2,2), (3,1))
a: List[Any] = List((0,0), (1,1), (1,3), (2,2), (3,1))

scala> a.asInstanceOf[List[(Int, Int)]]
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,0), (1,1), (1,3), (2,2), (3,1))
```

Though this is dangerous because of partial erasure. See how it can create [heap pollution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_pollution):

```
scala> val a: List[Any] = List((0,0), (1,1), "abc")
a: List[Any] = List((0,0), (1,1), abc)

scala> a.asInstanceOf[List[(Int, Int)]]
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,0), (1,1), abc)
```

So do this only if performance is a big concern here. Otherwise, I prefer one of the other two answers (summarized below).

If you want failure in the form of `ClassCastException`([@mattinbits's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32520403/402884)):

```
a.map(_.asInstanceOf[(Int, Int)])
```

If you want failures to be passed over silently ([@grotrianster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32520369/402884)):

```
a.collect({ case (a: Int, b: Int) => (a, b) })
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a for comprehension, like this

```
 for ( (a:Int,b:Int) <- xs ) yield (a,b)
```

This will quietly skim pairs whose type signature do not match `[(Int,Int)]`.